# how to generate buttons equals to the number of "postId" property in the get api call array in angular10 using "ngFor" directive?

Tags: typescript, angular10

```
export class AlphaComponent implements OnInit {

apiData=[]; //this array contains the data from API.

constructor(private helpService:HelpService){ };

ngOnInit(){

    this.getData()

};

getData(){

    this.helpService.getPostId().subscribe((jsonData:any) =>{this.apiData = jsonData;

    this.helpService.setJasonData(this.apiData);

    console.log(this.apiData);

    //this.apiDataArray();

    });

};

apiDataArray(){                                    

    for(let value of this.apiData){ 

    console.log("Data in apiDataArray=>",value);

    };

};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> .html

```
    <ng-template *ngFor="let post of apiData">
     <button *ngIf="post.hasOwnProperty('postId')">Button</button>
    </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

export class AlphaComponent implements OnInit {

apiData=[]; //this array contains the data from API.

constructor(private helpService:HelpService){ };

ngOnInit(){

```
this.getData()
```

};

getData(){

```
this.helpService.getPostId().subscribe((jsonData:any) =>{this.apiData = jsonData;

this.helpService.setJasonData(this.apiData);

console.log(this.apiData);

this.apiDataArray();   //RUN THIS FOR LOOP

});
```

};

apiDataArray(){

```
for(let value of this.apiData){ 

console.log("Data in apiDataArray=>",value);

};
```

};}

========================================IN Alpha.component.html==========================

<button

```
class="btn btn-success" 

*ngFor="let buttons of 

apiData">{{buttons.postId}} //in place of "postId" any desired property value from the 
                                                                                api
```